# mysql raw not coming

Tags: mysql, sql

mysql table ->

Table name `td`

```
id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, band
varchar(4) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

I used -> `select * from td where band != 'band' order by id limit 20, 10;`

It gave me normal result. start from id 21. Then I changed id 15 band column content null to 'band', and I use earlier sql. But result start from id 22.  I changed raw 15 again to null. Now result normal.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please explain yourself better. I see two people have attempted to clean up the question, but it's still very vague. Especially your comment about 21, 15 and 22.. Please use SQL terms and point to code to explain yourself.

Comment: offset playing the role in limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "band" column is having `NOT NULL` property. How did you change row 15's "band" column from null to 'band'? `Then I changed id 15 band column content null to 'band'`

And, what's wrong with the result? It's supposed to skip row 15 because you changed it's value to 'band' which doesn't fulfill the condition `where band != 'band'` anymore. "limit" controls the number of rows that you wanna select, not the range of your primary key. In this case it's working as expected because the query returns rows at ID 1~14 and 16~* and it displays from the 20th rows which is ID 22.

If what you want to control is actually the range of ID you have to do it in the WHERE cause instead of LIMIT. Something like this,

```
select * from td where band != 'band' and id > 20 order by id limit 10;
```

This will starts from 21.